# I am trying to get the RETWEETS a person has done on his profile. How can I achieve this using R programming? Read below

Tags: r, twitter

I used twitteR package.I need to extract all the tweets Mr X has done and all the Retweets Mr X had done (I am not talking about which of his tweets are retweeted).

```
tweets = userTimeline("@X", n=1000)
```

This code only gives me his tweets and doesn't include the retweets he has on his profile. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `includeRts`:

```
library(twitteR)
# ... authorize ... 
screenname <- "username"
tweets <- userTimeline(screenname, includeRts=TRUE)
df <- twListToDF(tweets)
df[df$isRetweet, 1]
```

See `?userTimeline` to view the help and explanations for each parameter.

Comment: Glad it worked @Varunkadekar. Feel free to click the check mark next to the answer to mark the question as solved, if it solved your problem.